# Outlook Add-in Auto pin add-in button to ribbon

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in that adds a button to the: AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface.

But I was wondering if it was possible to auto pin this button to the ribbon.

I figured out that its possible using:
Select Settings> View all Outlook settings > Mail > Customize actions, **but is this process also automatable using code (The add-in itself)?**

I don't want the user of the add-in to have to manually pin it to the ribbon...

Comment: Is this Win32? What Version? Buttons should automatically be added to the ribbon. When you install the add-in. Are you in simplified or classic ribbon mode? If in simplified your button will show up as long as there is room in the ribbon. If there is not, it will move to the overflow menu. There is no process to automate this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT
Ah, sorry for not clarifying, Yes the button is automatically ADDED to the ribbon (So that works fine). But since it is an add-in, the button is added at the END of the ribbon.
And most of the time that means that there is not enough space so it gets placed in the dropdown. Now I don't think there is a way set the position of the button to be the first in the ribbon, so instead I would at least like it to show in the ribbon itself and not in the overflow-dropdown. (This can be done using the user settings), but is there a way to automate this process using code?

Comment: If there is a way to get the addin as the first button of the ribbon than that would be an even better solution! (But don't think that that is possible)

Comment: Currently customizing the ribbon addin order, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process, but generally we don't allow add-ins to supersede user preferences.